# geometry package doesn't change textheight?

Tags: geometry

When I compile this MWE, I get a box that takes up about 80% of a vertical page.  Since I have specified `max height=0.4\textheight` in `adjustbox`, I'd expect a box half the size... is `geometry` not changing `\textheight`?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[landscape,hmargin={1.2cm,1cm},vmargin=1cm,footskip=7mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{boxedminipage}

\begin{document}
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth,max height=0.4\textheight,keepaspectratio}
\begin{boxedminipage}{70cm}
\ \vspace{70cm}\ 
\end{boxedminipage}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just a guess: doesn't `keepaspectratio` overwrite the height setting?

Comment: @Mohan not sure what you trying to achieve your boxedminipage is 70cm?

Comment: @Yiannis Lazarides: I just needed something that was much bigger than the page, to make sure that the `adjustbox` would shrink it. I couldn't find a cleaner way of drawing a  huge square, so I just used `boxedminipage`.

Comment: `{\fboxsep=-\fboxrule\framebox[70cm]{\rule{0pt}{70cm}}}`

Comment: @egreg: thanks! I would say that's worth turning into a question + answer --- I did search, and couldn't find anything that didn't require `tikz`, which seems like overkill.

Comment: `\newcommand{\bigsquare}[1]{{\fboxsep=-\fboxrule\sbox0{}\wd0=#1\ht0=#1\relax\fbox{\box0}}}` and then `\bigsquare{70cm}` is even faster.

Comment: @egreg: would it be all right if I ask a question about this so that you can turn `bigsquare` into an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\textheight` *is* changing as you can verify by adding the `verbose` option to `geometry` and looking in the log file.  The problem is the `adjustbox` command.  Changing `max height` to `max totalheight` gives the desired behaviour.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[landscape,hmargin={1.2cm,1cm},vmargin=1cm,footskip=7mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{boxedminipage}

\begin{document}
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth,max totalheight=0.4\textheight,keepaspectratio}
\begin{boxedminipage}{70cm}
\ \vspace{70cm}\ 
\end{boxedminipage}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{document}
```

If you do the following

```
\newsavebox{\test}

\settoheight{\test}{\begin{boxedminipage}{70cm}
  \ \vspace{70cm}\ 
\end{boxedminipage}}
\showthe\\test

\sbox{\test}{\begin{boxedminipage}{70cm}
  \ \vspace{70cm}\ 
\end{boxedminipage}}
\showthe\ht{\test}
```

then the log file will show that your boxed minipage has height `1001.74644pt` and depth `996.74644pt` so its total height is about twice its height.  (The values are close to being such that the box is vertially centered with respect to the middle of the current row.)

`boxedminipage` is just like `minipage`, so you can give it positioning arguments: a `\begin{boxedminipage}[b]` results in a box with zero depth and full height; `\begin{boxedminipage}[t]` results in a box with height `0.4pt` and (nearly) full depth (the `0.4pt` comes from the frame).  So instead of using `totalheight`, you could use

```
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth,max height=0.4\textheight,keepaspectratio}
  \begin{boxedminipage}[b]{70cm}
    \ \vspace{70cm}\
  \end{boxedminipage}
\end{adjustbox}
```

Comment: THank you. What's the difference between `height` and `totalheight`? (I've looked at the documentation, but the only difference I can see is that `totalheight` is overridden by `textheight`.)

Comment: @Mohan A `minipage` (and `boxedminipage` too) has not only a height, but also a depth: it extends below the baseline (almost) as much it extends above it. You so occupied 80% of the available height just because of this.